# Laptop missing power delivery charging or hasn't been implemented

Tags: laptop, battery

Can I add Power Delivery to a lapop that doesn't currently support it?

I have 2 Thunderbolt 4 ports on each side but they are output only and cannot charge.

What if I would add or link wire from usb-c where it is terminated and link it with power regulator chip to support 8V or 9V to the battery?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Supported charging protocols are based on hardware and firmware controlling it. You would need to change substantial parts of the system to add this feature.